# Prove that the function has a smallest positive period...

Tags: calculus

Let $ f \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be continuous, periodic and non-constant. Prove that $ f $ then has a smallest positive period $ p $ and all other periods are integer-valued multiples of $ p $.

no ideas... please give me a hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\;P\;$ be the set of periods of the function $\;f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\;.$

$P\;$ is non-empty and bounded below by $0$.

Let us consider $\;p^*=\inf P\;.$

There exist a sequence $\;\left\{p_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq P\;$ such that $\;p_n\to p^*$.

Let $\;x\;$ be any real number. Then $\;x+p_n \to x+p^*$ and $f(x+p^*)=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\left(x+p_n\right)=f(x)$.

If $\;p^*$ were equal to zero, there would be the positive numbers $p_1,p_2,\dots$, tending to zero such that $f(x+p_n) = f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Moreover, if $x\neq y$ were any two distinct points, we could make $x$ and $y + m\cdot p_n$ as close as we like by choosing appropriate values of $m$ and $n$. This would imply, by the continuity of $f$, that $f$ should take the same value at $x$ and $y$, i.e., that $f$ would be constant.

So $\;p^*>0\;$, then $\;p^*\in P\;$ and $\;p^*= \min P\;.$

It means that the function $\;f\;$ has a smallest positive period that is $\;p^*.$

Now we are going to prove that $\;\forall\;p\in P\;$ there exists $\;\lambda\in\mathbb{N}\;$ such that $\;p=\lambda\cdot p^*$.

Let $\;p\;$ be any element of $\;P\;$ and let $\;\lambda\in\mathbb{N}\;$ the greatest positive integer number such that $\;p-\lambda\cdot p^*\ge0\;.$

If $\;q=p-\lambda\cdot p^*$ were positive, then it would result that $\;0<q<p^*$ and $\;f(x+q)=f(x)\;$ for all $\;x\in\mathbb{R}\;.$

It means that $\;q\in P\;,$ but it is impossible because $\;q<p^*=\min P\;.$

Hence $\;q=0\;,$ so $\;p=\lambda\cdot p^*.$

Comment: And what about the "all other periods are integer-valued multiples of $p$" part? ;) But don't try too hard: the "no ideas" code phrase usually means that the OP won't understand your answer, anyway.